# Unable to Initialize char array

Tags: arrays, c++11, char

Im trying to see why the following code does not work:

```
void test2() {
    char ulu[256];
    ulu[]{ "Hello","Hello" };

}
```

But this code works:

```
struct my_test
{
    char test_array[256];
};

void test() {
    my_test test_array[]{ "hello", "hello" };
    printf("%s", test_array);
}
```

I would expect both codes to fail but only the first one does

Can someone explain to me why it works when declaring and initializing the variable test_array as an object of the my_test class?

Im getting an error stating:

```
a value of type "const char *" cannot be used to initialize an entity of type "char"
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Maybe you want `char ulu[][256] = { "Hello","Hello" };` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can someone explain to me why it works when declaring and initializing
>   the variable test_array as an object of the my_test class?

```
char ulu[256];
ulu[]{ "Hello","Hello" };
```

This is not the right syntax.

What you want is something like this:

```
char ulu[][256] {
  "Hello",
  "Hello"
};

for (auto const& i : ulu)
  std::cout << i << '\n';
```

Output:

> ```
> Hello
> Hello
> ```

A more modern approach would use `std::vector` or `std::array`

Answer (score 0):

Since test() uses [uniform initialization](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/uniform-initialization-in-c/), it's compiled correctly.
test2() seems doing an assignment. You can't use uniform initialization when assignment.